# Could not unmarshal / marshal... Could not load class

Tags: rest, marshalling, sap-commerce-cloud, unmarshalling

We expose REST endpoints for GET and PUT requests. Example for PUT requests:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{segment}",
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}
    )
@Secured({...})
public ResponseEntity createR(@RequestBody FakeData fakeData, @PathVariable("test") String test...
```

When I am testing these endpoints, I get different results between server re-starts or even postman close/open.
[image]

On the other side, the exceptions are always constant:
[image]

- Hybris versions: 2105 and 2211
- Happens across several environments

I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue with no success. Has someone come across a similar issue ?